# How to send a voice message handsfree in iMessage?

Tags: iphone, audio, messages

How can you send a voice message on iPhone handsfree?

The time I want to record a voice message is precisely when I can't use hands, but the iMessage app has a button that you have to **Tap and hold to record and send audio.**

Is there a way to record one without having to hold down the button?

*Note:* I don't want to dictate a text message, I want to send an audio message.

Comment: would shortcuts work? I don't exactly know if they have audio recorder, but if they do, turn on the timer, start audio, finish recording, send audio, exit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured this out today! You press the audio message button and then you swipe left and it will record without having to long hold. It will only record when your phone is unlocked, so tap your screen if you want it to be longer than your auto-lock, or change your auto-lock settings. Hope this helps, even though it’s delayed.

Comment: An answer almost 2 years later!  It works, thanks.

Comment: Awesome. Glad you got notified!